# How do you remove a native websocket handler when setting with ws.onmessage = myFunc; or ws.onopen = function(){}?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am setting websocket handlers on native websocket created with `new WebSocket()` using `ws.onopen = myFunc;`

How would I remove that event handler when I no longer need it?

I am not in a position to use socket.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set it back to its initial value, `undefined`, or to `null`:

```
ws.onopen = null;
```